# Can't run default Qt Quick Application StackView Template: "The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

I used default template "Qt Quick application with stackview" to start a new project, **didn't make any modification**, and could build it successfully, but couldn't debug it, the error was:

"The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in thread 14 by: Exception at 0x7fff93dc7cac, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0.0 (first chance)."

If I left it there for around 30s then Qt Creator would totally crash. I also tried to directly build in release mode then the application would crash.

If I **commented out the "Stackview" definition section** in main.qml then the it can run normally. I also tried swipeview, and had to comment out both "Swipeview" section and "footer" section to make it work. Scroll template worked fine.

The environment is:

Win10

Qt 5.10.1

Qt Creator 4.5.1 with CDB debugger

MSVC 2017 64bit

windows SDK 10.0.16299.91 (for CDB)

What's the problem, are there something wrong with environment? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Just found out that if comment out only the line specifying "initialItem" it also worked

Comment: Highly doubt anyone other than a psychic would be able to answer. You will have to debug to find the origin of the exception, and since it is just a template project with no user code, you will most likely have to file a bug report.

Comment: @dtech Just found out that if comment out only the line specifying "initialItem" it also worked. What might be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of struggle I found out it's a bug, please see this:
[QTBUG-64697](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64697)

My computer happens to be i5-6300HQ and HD Graphics 530. Setting "QT_OPENGL" environment variable to "angle" solved the problem.